Prove that $M\otimes_A(N\otimes_B P)\simeq (M\otimes_A N)\otimes_B P$ using universal property.
Let $A, B$ be two commutative rings with identity and let $M$ be an $A$-module, $N$ an $(A,B)$-bimodule, and $P$ an $B$-module. How do you use universal property of tensor product to show that $$M\otimes_A(N\otimes_B P)\simeq (M\otimes_A N)\otimes_B P?$$I know you can prove by construction that $M\otimes_A N$ is an $B$-module and that $N\otimes_B P$ is an $A$-module, but is it possible that we only use abstract categorical properties of tensor products without using individual tensors?
For example over here, I don’t know how to regard $M\otimes_A N$ as an $B$-module. How can I use universal property here?

Literally any proof you find for this uses only the universal properties (what else?), and the proof also hast appeared on this site. To make a good question, please 1) research for a proof which comes close to your needs, 2) explain in detail why this proof is not yet sufficient, 3) ask a specific question about this proof.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you for the suggestion. I have added to the question body.

Hint for the module structure: use that the tensor product is a functor in the 2nd variable.

@MartinBrandenburg Sorry - I don’t see how I can have a module structure using the fact that tensor product is a functor on the second variable.

For $b \in B$ right multiplication with $b$ is an $A$-linear map $N \to N$. Hence, we get an $A$-linear map $M \otimes N \to M \otimes N$. This is then the right module structure. Alternatively, using associativity: $(M \otimes N) \otimes B \cong M \otimes (N \otimes B) \to M \otimes N$. All of this is well-known, really (meaning, you can read it up in several places on comm. alg.), and (as in your other q) holds for all monoidal categories.

@MartinBrandenburg I haven’t see this categorical points of view to universal constructions in commutative algebra in for example A&M, Matsumura. Would there be a reference that you could recommend that won’t avoid categorical languages for commutative algebra? Sorry for these questions since I haven’t learned any of these approaches from the standard textbooks.

@MartinBrandenburg Also for the "using associativity" part how does $(M\otimes_A N)\otimes B$ make sense? Either $B$ has to be an $A$-module which is not assumed, or that you mean  $(M\otimes_A N)\otimes_B B$ so that we are already assuming $M\otimes_A N$ is an $B$-module. The first approach makes sense.
